# How do I integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} [x\sin x]\,dx $, where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Integrate

$$\int_0^{2\pi} [x\sin x]\,dx, $$where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Plot the function, and break the integral into intervals where it is constant.

The idea is to find where $[x \sin  x]  = 1$, then $[x\sin x] = 2$ and so on.

$\hskip1.9in$[image]

Comment: How do you find the length of each interval?

Comment: please show me the steps how you have reached here....???

Comment: @Pratyush Computationally, using Mathematica. Where did you find this problem? To find the values you will have to use computer. The idea to integrate this function is here though.